# Excel VBA changing value of cell with one click - assign this to multiple ranges independently

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to setup a vba code so I will be able to click on a specific number of cells and have these cells switch between "nothing", "cr" & "cv". So far I have this in my code but I need to assign it to multiple targets but I can't seem to get them to work independently.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  With Target
     If .Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        Select Case .Value
           Case ""
             .Value = "CR"
           Case "CR"
             .Value = "CV"
           Case "CV"
             .Value = ""
           Case Else
             .Value = "CR"
        End Select
     End If
  End With

  Range("A2").Select
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way of achieving what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 07 May 2017

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Range("A1,B2:B4,C3,D4")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address(False, False) & " was clicked."
    End If
End Sub
```

I observed that your first `Select` statement is superfluous because it is identical with the last. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this : )

Comment: You dont need that loop to define a multiple-area range. You can simply use `Set Rng = Range("A1,B2,C3,D4")`

Comment: @A.S.H. Thanks. I have amended my answer to incorporate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Mapleleaf,
I'm not altogether sure that I understand completely what you're after, but this worked for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For Each T In Target
        With T
           'If .Address = Range("A1").Address Then
              Select Case .Value
                 Case ""
                   .Value = "CR"
                 Case "CR"
                   .Value = "CV"
                 Case "CV"
                   .Value = ""
                 Case Else
                   .Value = "CR"
              End Select
           'End If
        End With
    Next
  Range("A2").Select
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If this turns out not to be what you were trying to accomplish, I suspect you'll be able to easily adapt it to do what you need. Hope this helps. If you have any questions, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it works great. Thank you for your help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C8:C10:C12:C14:C16:I8:I10:I12:I14:I16:O8:O10:O1:O14:O16:U8:U10:U12:U14:U16:AA8:AA10:AA12:AA14:AA16:AG8:AG10:AG12:AG14:AG16:AM8:AM10:AM12:AM14:AM16")) Is Nothing Then
      Select Case Target.Value
      Case ""
        Target.Value = "CR"
      Case "CR"
        Target.Value = "CV"
      Case "CV"
        Target.Value = ""
      Case Else
        Target.Value = "CR"
      End Select
      Range("B2").Select
    End If
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```